# How to create a lot of categories for card laravel voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkJD7.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB5Mx.png)

Now I have like this
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6uHA.png)
but I want have more categories
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erTN6.png)

How to select many category?

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say in your case, we need to define the category for every features. So feature can have many categories and inverse category can have many features. Thus, it will be a Many To Many relationships.

To accomplish this we need to create 3 tables `features`, `categories`, and intermediate table `feature_category`. The `feature_category` table will have the `feature_id` and `category_id` column which connects both feature and category table and this intermediate table called the pivot table.

Here are the table structures:

```
features
    id - integer
    name - string
 
categories
    id - integer
    name - string
 
feature_category
    feature_id - integer
    category_id - integer
```

=> category

```
id  name                 
--  -------    
1   Category 1
2   Category 2
3   Category 3
4   Category 4
```

=> features

```
id  name                 
--  -------    
1   Feature 1
2   Feature 2
3   Feature 3
4   Feature 4
```

=> feature_category

```
id  feature_id   category_id            
--  -------        -------
1      1              1
2      2              2
3      3              2
4      3              3
4      3              4
```

===============================

Our feature_category table before sync() operation:

```
id  feature_id   category_id            
--  -------        -------
1      1              1
2      2              2
3      2              3
4      2              4
5      3              2
6      4              3
```

Laravel Sync() example:

```
<?php
 
    use App\Models\Feature;
 
    $user = Feature::find(2);
 
    // Want to keep only "Category 2" (Id 2) category
    $user->category()->sync([2]);
```

After performing the above operation, our feature_category table will look like below:

```
id  feature_id   category_id            
--  -------        -------
1      1              1
2      2              2
5      3              2
6      4              3
```

Checkboxes or dropdowns can be used from the frontend to select multiple categories for features and sync() method can be used to update feature cards accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

- First you need to create new table `feature_category` with two fields :

  ```
   (same type of features.id)  feature_id 
   (same type of categories.id) category_id
  ```
- Second create  `belongsToMany` relationship directly in Voyager.

***Example :***

[image]